# BlackBerry: check if headless app is running

Tags: qt, blackberry, blackberry-10, headless

This is just a short question, but very important:

In my UI app, I'd like to print out some debug information. There should be a note like `Service running` or `Service not running`.

Is there any *easy* possibility to check whether the headless part is running or not?

Thanks!

**edit**

searched, but nothing found!

Answer (score 0):

Yes in your headless service class u can put a debug if your headless app is running then it will prints debug text in console.

Comment: can you specify more precisely, maybe with an example? i think the question is to check from the UI part